# help for solve that case

Tags: 16.04

```
adel@Adel:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for adel: 
PATH: command not found
PATH: command not found
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
 * /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
root@Adel:/home/adel#
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.bashrc`, you have a <kbd>Space</kbd> between `PATH` and `=`. This makes the shell's parser think `PATH` is a command.

Comment: i dont write PATH in the terminal and i cant open ~ /.bashrc with gedit from sudo -i

Comment: Inspect `~user/.bashrc` and `~root/.bashrc`. Read `man bash` on "Startup files". Look in all files `source`d (or included with `.`). Search for the string `"PATH "` in the startup files (`grep "PATH " ~/.bashrc ~root/.bashrc ...`). `gedit` is another problem. Use `vim` instead for this one. Summary: Wrong `"PATH ="`; Right `"PATH="` (no blank)